# Windows Batch - Moving Incorrect files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a batch script which will move folders on various servers to the host server.

The script starts by asking the user to input a a number, between 0-20
this will calculate a date a user would like to access, and move the log files of that date to the host server. Currently it's working, but at times I also get files older then the specified date.

Basically, the script will not only retrieve files with the said date.
Instead it will move files of any date, older or newer depending on the date chosen.

Question: so the code is moving files which are not the specified date as well, either older or newer depending on the date chosen. Why is this? I would only like to move files with the specified date.

Image for reference. Here the date was 07-14, yet there is a file from 07-12
[image]

Code:

```
@echo on

:GETDAY
set /p dayCnt=Enter The Days you would like to go back [0-20]:%=%
@echo %dayCnt%
@echo off

if %dayCnt% LSS 0 goto GETDAY
if %dayCnt% GTR 20  goto GETDAY

Set ServerList= CANT SHOW

set $tok=1-3
for /f "tokens=1 delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do set $d1=%%u
if "%$d1:~0,1%" GTR "9" set $tok=2-4
for /f "tokens=%$tok% delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do (
 for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=/-,()." %%x in ('echo.^|date') do (
    set %%x=%%u
    set %%y=%%v
    set %%z=%%w
    set $d1=
    set $tok=))

if "%yyyy%"=="" set yyyy=%yy%
if /I %yyyy% LSS 100 set /A yyyy=2000 + 1%yyyy% - 100

set CurDate=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%

::set dayCnt=%1

REM Substract your days here
set /A dd=1%dd% - 100 - %dayCnt%
set /A mm=1%mm% - 100

:CHKDAY

if /I %dd% GTR 0 goto DONE

set /A mm=%mm% - 1

if /I %mm% GTR 0 goto ADJUSTDAY

set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1

@echo %dayCnt%
pause

:ADJUSTDAY

if %mm%==1 goto SET31
if %mm%==2 goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 goto SET31
if %mm%==4 goto SET30
if %mm%==5 goto SET31
if %mm%==6 goto SET30
if %mm%==7 goto SET31
if %mm%==8 goto SET31
if %mm%==9 goto SET30
if %mm%==10 goto SET31
if %mm%==11 goto SET30
REM ** Month 12 falls through

:SET31

set /A dd=31 + %dd%

goto CHKDAY

:SET30

set /A dd=30 + %dd%

goto CHKDAY

:LEAPCHK

set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4

if not %tt%==0 goto SET28

set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100

if not %tt%==0 goto SET29

set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400

if %tt%==0 goto SET29

:SET28

set /A dd=28 + %dd%

goto CHKDAY

:SET29

set /A dd=29 + %dd%

goto CHKDAY

:DONE

if /I %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
if /I %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%

Set CurrentDir=%~dp0

set yyyy=%Date:~-4%
set yy=%Date:~-2%

set date1=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
Set date2=%dd%%mm%%yy%
Set date3=%yy%%mm%%dd%


@echo Date: %date1%
SET /P ANSWER=Do you want to continue(Y/N)?
echo you seletced %ANSWER%

if /i {%ANSWER%}=={n} (exit) 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (exit) 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={N} (exit)

mkdir %CurrentDir%\Incoming
mkdir %CurrentDir%\IIS
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Performance
mkdir %CurrentDir%\SystemLogs
mkdir %CurrentDir%\EventLogs
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Integration
mkdir %CurrentDir%\W6OptimizerLog



set Incoming=%CurrentDir%\incoming


REM ## Gather Integration Log files ##
set Source1=d$\clicklogs\integrationlog
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\Integration

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\%%S_W6IntLogIncoming_*%date1%-00* %Incoming%\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\%%S_W6IntLogoutgoing_*%date1%-00* %Incoming%\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\W6IntLogIncoming_*%date1%* %Incoming%\%%S_W6IntIncoming_%date1%.txt
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\W6IntLogoutgoing_*%date1%* %Incoming%\%%S_W6IntLogoutgoing_%date1%.txt
if exist %Incoming%\*.txt (
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\IntegrationLogs_%date1% %Incoming%\*.txt
del /Q %Incoming%\*.txt
)

)



REM ## Gather Application Event Log files ##
set Source1=d$\ClickLogs\EventLogs\Application
set Source2=d$\ClickLogs\AppEvntLogs
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\EventLogs

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Incoming\%%S
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*%date1%* %Incoming%\%%S\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*%date1%* %Incoming%\%%S\

Rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.* %Incoming%\%%S\

rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*%.evtx%* %Incoming%\%%S\

copy /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*%.evtx%* %Incoming%\%%S\
copy /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*%.evtx%* %Incoming%\%%S\
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\ApplicationEventLogs_%date1% %Incoming%\*
For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO rd /S /Q %Incoming%\%%S
)


REM ## Gather System Event Log files ##
set Source1=d$\ClickLogs\SystemEventLogs
set Source2=d$\ClickLogs\EventLogs\System
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\SystemLogs

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.evtx %Incoming%\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*.evtx %Incoming%\

rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*.* %Incoming%\


copy /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.evtx %Incoming%\

copy /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*.evtx %Incoming%\
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\SystemEventLogs_%date1% %Incoming%\*.evtx
del /Q %Incoming%\*.evtx
)



REM ## Gather IIS Log files ##
set Source1=d$\ClickLogs\InetLogs\W3SVC1
set Source2=d$\inetpub\logs\logfiles\W3SVC1
set Source3=d$\ClickLogs\InetLogs\W3SVC1\W3SVC1
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\IIS

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Incoming\%%S

move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*%date3%*.log %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log
move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*%date3%*.log %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log
move /Y \\%%S\%Source3%\*%date3%*.log %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log

rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.* %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log
rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source2%\*.* %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log
rem move /Y \\%%S\%Source3%\*.* %Incoming%\%%S\%%S_IIS_%date1%.log


)
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\IISLogs_%date1% %Incoming%\*
For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO rd /S /Q %Incoming%\%%S

REM ## Gather W6OptimizerLog Log files ##
set Source1=d$\clicklogs
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\W6OptimizerLog

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Incoming\%%S
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\W6OptimizerLog_%date1%*.txt %Incoming%\%%S\
)
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\W6OptimizerLog_%date1% %Incoming%\*
For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO rd /S /Q %Incoming%\%%S

REM ## Gather Performance Log files ##
set Source1=d$\clicklogs\"Performance Monitor Logs"
set Destination=%CurrentDir%\Performance

For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO (
mkdir %CurrentDir%\Incoming\%%S
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*%date3%*.csv %Incoming%\%%S\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*%date3%*.blg %Incoming%\%%S\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.blg %Incoming%\%%S\
move /Y \\%%S\%Source1%\*.csv %Incoming%\%%S\
)
d:\backups\7za.exe a %Destination%\PerformanceLogs_%date1% %Incoming%\*
For %%S IN (%ServerList%) DO rd /S /Q %Incoming%\%%S
```

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Comment: i've editted the post to add the 'question' @aschipfl